# Querying iOS AppStore for App Information?

Tags: ios, app-store

I want to have a listing of iOS apps within another iOS app. The individual items of the listing then link back to the AppStore for each app. No problem there.

I also want to be able to get app specific information -- App Name, description, URL to the app's icon -- by querying the AppStore with an App ID. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Responds with JSON:

```
http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=
```

Here is the documentation: http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html#lookup

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to display the apps for a specific developer, then `SKStoreProductViewController` might do the trick without the need to do any parsing.

How To: https://www.cocoanetics.com/2015/03/implementing-an-in-app-app-store/